# Invariant factor decomposition of $\mathbb{Z}_6 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensors, free-abelian-group

I recall the elementary divisor forms of abelian groups from early chapters but I'm unsure about how to deal with it when it's the tensor of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Does anyone have any guidance for this problem?

Comment: Is $\;\Bbb Z_6=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\;$ ?

Comment: Yes this is just the shorthand notation

Answer (score 0):

In general
$$\Bbb Z_n\otimes_{\Bbb Z} A\cong A/nA$$
whenever $A$ is an Abelian group. So, what is $6\Bbb Z_9$?

Comment: Is that just the same as $3\mathbb{Z}_9,$ which would be $\{0, 3, 6\}$?